# Matlab: Finding max YData among Line array

Tags: matlab, plot, max

I have the following Matlab script

```
x = linspace(0, 2, 11);
l = plot(x, x, x, x.^2, x, x.^3);
```

the object `l` is a `3×1 Line array`. If I type on the command line `l.Ydata` it gives the `Ydata` for its three elements. Is there a way to obtain a global `max` of the `Ydata` for the whole array (without a loop)?

EDIT:
The trivial solution

```
M = max(max(max(l(1).YData), max(l(2).YData)), max(l(3).YData));
```

is trivial, but is not what I'm looking for. I'd like something that generalizes on larger arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all of the `YData` properties of `l` using `l(:).YData`.

By surrounding this with square brackets, we can concatenate them all into one array and find the max:

```
m = max( [l(:).YData] );
```